# Reading files in particular order?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I would like to read a lot of files from different folders. Now I asking myself what is the smartest way. For now Im using

```
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(myPath);
    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

so I have a list with all the files and I can iterate through them (read them one by one).

Is that alright? Is there a way to reorder the list, so that I have **always** the oldest file at the top. Thats maybe a good ide, because I would like to start reading the oldest file and at last the newest. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<FileInfo> files = directory
    .GetFiles("*.txt")
    .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
    .ToList();
```

See [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and [FileSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx) for a comprehensive list of fields you can order by.

Here's an [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/ntsmith/archive/2006/08/17/88250.aspx) in VB.NET

Answer (score 4):

You could fetch the files from the directory and then just sort them by their creation date:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(myPath);
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

Now the `files` array contains your files ordered by their creation date. And by altering the lambda expression from `OrderBy`, you can sort them by anything:

- by last modified time: `OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)`
- by name: `OrderBy(f => f.Name)`

..and so on. Your output also doesn't *have* to be an array. It can be converted to a `List<FileInfo>`, as well, by replacing the final `ToArray()` with a `ToList()`.

And if you ever need to sort in reverse order, you can simply use `OrderByDescending(...)` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

After your code, do this:

```
FileInfo[] orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

.. or better yet, get them sorted in the first place:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(myPath);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt")
                   .OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToArray();
```